# sort column and 0 come at last with case when

Tags: mysql, case-when

How to sort column and 0 come at last with case when?
Below is query:

```
SELECT iAdminID
     , vFirstName
     , vLastName
     , iRank 
  FROM tbl_admin 
 WHERE eDeleted = 'No' 
   AND eStatus = 'Active' 
 ORDER 
    BY CASE WHEN iAdminID = 1 
            THEN 0 
            ELSE iRank=0 END
```

Below is result for above query:

[image: Query Resulr]

> But what I want is, first record should be as it is and others should
>   be according to iRank (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,0,0,0)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method is to use severallevels of sorting.

You could do:

```
order by
    case when iAdmin = 1 then 0 else 1 end,
    case when iRank = 0 then 1 else 0 end,
    iRank
```

In MySQL this can also be expressed as follows:

```
order by 
    (iAdmin = 1) desc,
    iRank = 0,
    iRank
```

A last option: if you know in advance the upper limit for `iRank` (say, no `iRank` will ever be greater than 1000), then you can skip one level:

```
order by 
    (iAdmin = 1) desc,
    case when iRank = 0 then 1000 else iRank end
```

Comment: but as I mentioned, `iAdminID 1` should be always on top, this is logged in id. I want loggedin user at top.

Comment: @PathikVejani: I updated my answer with this rule as well.